# Blank space in Twitter direct messages with tweepy from JSON API

Tags: python, json, tweepy

So I have the following python code which receives notification of received direct messages via Tweepy:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
import simplejson as json

consumer_key = "secret"
consumer_secret = "secret"

access_token = "secret"
access_token_secret = "secret"

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
    def __init__(self):
        print "init"

    def on_connect(self):
        print "Connected"

    def on_disconnect(self, status):
        print ("Disconnected", status)

    def on_direct_message(self, status):
        print ("on_direct_message", status)

    def on_data(self, status):
        # print ("on_data", status)

        decoded = json.loads(status)

        ## grab the direct message
        directMessage = decoded['direct_message']

        message = directMessage.get('text', None)
        message.strip() 
        print "message:*", message, "*"
    return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print ("on_error", status)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ##  Connect to Twitter
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    ## Init the  StreamListener
    print ("Init Stream")
    l = StdOutListener()
    stream = Stream(auth, l)
    stream.userstream()
```

When it runs and I send the direct message "test message" I get the following printed to the console:

```
message:* text message *
```

ie the message was received and parsed but padded with space at either end which message.strip() didn't even correct. If I uncomment the print directMessage line and view the json sent by Twitter there is no space.

I cannot work out if there is a problem with my JSON editing or usage of tweepy or something else.

I've also tried using the json package as well as simplejson.

Comment: It is the print statement that adds the spaces.

Comment: Ah, I see. I should use print "message:*" + message + "*". Thank you for saving my sanity :-)